# Blackberry BES Privacy

Tags: blackberry, privacy

I work on a mobile operator company, which gave a Blackberry device connected to our BES, so I can stay in touch with my email.

Although, I configured my own personal GMAIL in the device too.

My question is can the company monitor my personal emails?

What about my SMS, Calls, etc?

My primary concern is my personal gmail.

Thanks!

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions.  I suggest superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail uses SSL, so everything is encrypted.

Second, all BES traffic is encrypted too, and the company can't read the traffic.

Some will tell you can always decrypt it, but I don't think your company really care, they could just block gmail from your phone, or block applications.